# easy access to cluster of html elements?

Tags: jquery

I have li and each entry have many html elements (the below is a very simple example)
each ID is a sequence of the row,
I am iterating over the il, and doing manipulation on the data

for example:
   for each row
   check this row input 1 if its greater then 5 put value of P in the hidden value of the same row

I want to know if there is an easy access to the cluster of objects I get in the for loop for processing

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   
    $("ol li").each( function( index, element ){
            console.log( $( this ).text() );
            // looking for easy way to access the current html tag cluster
            //if(this row input is greater then 5)
            //     take the value of this row P
            //           put it in hidden
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
 <li>
  <div id="1">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_1">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_1" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="2">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_2">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_2" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="3">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_3">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_3" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="4">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_4">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_4" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="5">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_5">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_5" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="6">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_6">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_6" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="7">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_7">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_7" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="8">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_8">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_8" type="hidden" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="9">Text</div><p>text</p>
  <div id="other_9">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_9" type="hidden" />
 </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: What is *this row input*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention "check this row input 1 if its greater then 5", do you mean you want to check the input value or the `p` value within each `li`? I made you a little working example based off of using the value from the `p` tag (I think this is what you meant). You can then use the `.find()` method to help you out. Now when you run the code below, you can see in the console that the rows with a value greater than 5 will display `P` in the hidden text input value. Again I could be wrong here but just wanted to give something you could possibly work with.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ol li").each(function(index, element) {
    var li = $(element).find('p').text();
    var input = $(element).find('input');
    if (li > 5) input.val('P');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
 <li>
  <div id="1">Text</div><p>10</p>
  <div id="other_1">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_1" type="hidden" value='' />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="2">Text</div><p>2</p>
  <div id="other_2">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_2" type="hidden" value='' />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="3">Text</div><p>6</p>
  <div id="other_3">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_3" type="hidden" value='' />
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="4">Text</div><p>4</p>
  <div id="other_4">Text</div>
  <input id="hid_4" type="hidden" value='' />
 </li>
  <!-- OTHER LI CONTENT BELOW WHEN READY -->
</ol>
```

Comment: so this $(element).find('p') will only find in the current row? 
also is there a difference using $(this) in the loop and element?      and what if i need to find a div in the cluster? i have many of them? with sequential IDS

Comment: @user648026 `$(element).find('p')` yes will only look in the current row. Using `$(this)` will get you the element and quite a few properties to go with it. `element` will give you just the `div` with it's children (you can use console.log() to check them both out too). If you want to find a `div`, you could do `$(element).find('div')`, but in your case that will give you both `div`'s. Option there is to use a class and `.find()` the class or you can choose which `div` you want like you would with any normal array, like such `$(element).find('div')[0]`. Hope this help clears some things up.